# Template specialization example

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

To my understanding, template specialization works as follows

```
template<typename T> 
void dummy(T a) { std::cout<<a<<std::endl; }

template<>
void dummy<int>(int a) { std::cout<<"special"<<std::endl; }
```

I was looking at the following code which checks if something is a pointer or not:

```
template<typename T> 
struct is_ptr { 
  constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_ptr<T*> { 
  constexpr static bool value = true; 
};
```

Is this still a template specialization? Why is the line `template <typename T>` there again in the specialization, and not `<>`. Is it because multiple specializations are generated by the compiler whenever we have `T*` rather than `T`?

Would this code expand to

```
template<>
struct is_ptr<int*>
{
  constexpr static bool value = true;
};
```

?

Comment: full specialization versus partial specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is a `function template specialization`. The `is_ptr` example is a `partial class template specialization`.

function templates cannot be paritially specailzied, class templates can be.

The reason for the `template <typename T>` in the class template partial specialization is precisely because it is specialized *partially* on pointers, but of any type `T`.

in your example when using `is_ptr<int*>::value`, the partial specialization will indeed be selected.